# Закінчення іменників душа, груша у родовому відмінку 1 відміни мішаної групи -и чи -і?

Tags: відмінювання, іменники

Допоможіть, будь ласка, друзі, правильно написати закінчення іменників *груша*, *душа* у родовому відмінку. Чим зумовлено написання відповідних закінчень?

Comment: Зазначу, що цей сайт передбачає якесь мінімальне дослідження власного питання самим автором. Результати цього дослідження мають міститися в самому тексті питання. В подальшому, якщо Ви ставитимете питання без мінімального дослідження самотужки, на них можуть не відповідати (а Ваші запитання можуть отримувати негативні оцінки спільноти).

Answer (score 1):

Обидва слова мають закінчення -і, *гр**у**ші, душ**і***, [відповідно до чинного правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par47):

> **§47.
>
>   А. Однина
>
>   Родовий відмінок**
>   1. У родовому відмінку однини іменники першої відміни мають закінчення **-и, -і, -ї**.
>   а) **И** мають іменники твердої групи: *кн**и**жки, маш**и**ни, перем**о**ги, род**и**ни, ф**а**брики*.
>   б) **І** (після голосного та апострофа — **ї**) мають іменники першої відміни м’якої та мішаної груп: *б**у**рі, мр**і**ї, над**і**ї, пр**а**ці, робітн**и**ці, сім’**ї**; кр**у**чі, меж**і**, пл**о**щі, т**и**ші*.